# Can't run utop in the terminal

Tags: terminal, cygwin, ocaml, utop

I have to start learning OCaml language.

In order to practice it at home we have to install some devices following the tutorial made by our University. Since we use Debian at school, it's a bit different when I have to use windows at home and here I come: I don't manage to run the tools properly.

We have to install OCaml via the official site. After doing it, I run "Cygwin64 Terminal" and had to type these commands:

```
$ opam update
$ opam install utop merlin ocp-indent
```

It has been done successfully. However when I try to run utop by its command I get this message:

> "utop.exe: GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo: Bad file descriptor"

Where did I fail? What do I have to do?

Comment: I assume you are running a NOT cygwin ocalm from cygwin shell/terminal. Try to run in from command shell (CMD.exe)

Comment: I tried, didn't work. Thanks for taking your time tho

Comment: check this for a better windows install https://diskuv.gitlab.io/diskuv-ocaml/

Answer (score -1):

I have the same error after installing ocaml for windows from http://fdopen.github.io/opam-repository-mingw/installation/   (graphic installer, 64 bits)
BUT the error happened ONLY after running opam install utop

Precisely, after running the graphic installer alone, I can launch ocaml (not utop) without error, either from a cygwin terminal or a windows shell (cmd.exe).

If I run opam install utop, I can no longer launch ocaml (cannot exec, segmentation fault) nor utop (GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo: Bad file descriptor)

If I uninstall utop and its dependencies, keeping only the base modules installed by the graphic installer, it is still impossible to launch ocaml.

Only solution found till now : completely remove ocaml and reinstall it ... but there's certainly a better way !

Comment: Well, remove and reinstall allowed me to launch ocaml, but NOT utop. For me it's enough, as I run ocaml from xemacs which offers nice editing facilities. But ocaml directly run in a cygwin terminal is somewhat harsh as you lack the facilities of utop.